# SOS mid of installaltion system reboots (Ubuntu 20.04 , HPDL380 G8 hardware

Tags: system-installation

I have two identical HP dL380 G8 hardware both of them acts weird during the Ubuntu 20.04/20.10 installation  - during installation after we give all input parameters server will be rebooted abnormally

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you verify the ISO prior to writing the media? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then verify the write to your media?  (you didn't say if desktop or server, my guess is server; but I'd switch to terminal & explore the problem yourself... problems covered in what I'm talking about show as *squashfs* errors)

Comment: Hi and welcome. No pictures of text please all text needs to be included in the question so every one can see them.

Comment: @guiverc its Server version , Media tested -Yes, Tried USB media installation  - Yes, verified Media by install another HW - yes

Comment: @David , i couldnt able pull out the log because its from HP ILOM console, i had tried to read, pretty long text file.  what i can do is just take screen shots from ILOM.